# Enterprise Architect - MDG Technology - Default Appearance as Icon

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am new for developing MDG Technology, wondering to get some help.

I have to create custom elements for my project and below is the requirement. While creating new elements in the diagram, the element should pick-up a default icon for appearance.

This is what I tried, (as guideline)

1. Created a Stereotype for my metaclass
2. In the Option : Edit with profile helper -- Assigned - icon (16 x 16) and _metatype: block

After generating MDG file and importing my MDG Technology, I tried to create a new element in my MDG diagram, but found that

1. In the toolbox - icon is assigned
2. When I drag and drop the element to create one, it has the default box. But here the expectation is the custom icon.

Any guidance, what exactly should I do to achieve this?

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the shapescript feature of your stereotype to modify the appearance on the diagrams.

Using the profile helper you click on the shape script tab and the button Edit.

You can use an image in the schapescript as well.
Below is an example from one of my stereotypes:

```
shape main
{
    DefSize(36,24);
    SetPenWidth(1);
    Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
    image("BAM icon_dial",2,3,98,97);
}
```

The `BAM icon_dial` has to be imported in the image manager